# articles_article.author_id Erro

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Eu estiva seguindo o tutorial de criação de blog utilizando a versão anterior do django 2.0 (esse aqui: https://youtu.be/zJWhizYFKP0), contudo eu utilizo a versão 2.0, no processo estive fazendo as alterações necessarias de syntaxe para o codigo funcionar, porem cheguei em um parte onde o 'articles_article.author_id' da erro, estive lendo a documentação do site Django e procurando por respostas, mas não encontrei o que em minhas linhas esta errado, em teoria era para funcionar. o erro somente ocorre nas paginas com as listas dos artigos, seja na criada no site ou na que vem pronta do django admin, criação de artigo e a home estão funcionando. Deixarei o erro seguindo da copia dos  codigos embaixo, ficarei muito agradecido se puderem me ajudar:

ERRO:

```
OperationalError at /articles/
no such column: articles_article.author_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: articles_article.author_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:  C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\daniel\\site\\djangosite',
 'C:\\Users\\daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 1 Jul 2019 16:12:41 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\daniel\site\djangosite\templates\base_layout.html, error at line 6

no such column: articles_article.author_id
1   {% load static from staticfiles %}
2   <!DOCTYPE html>
3   <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
4     <head>
5       <meta charset="utf-8">
6       <title>Articles</title>
7       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
8     </head>
9     <body>
10      <div class="wrapper">
11        <h1><a href="{% url 'articles:list' %}">Articles</a>
12          <nav>
13            <ul>
14              <li>
15                <form class="logout-link" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">
16                  {% csrf_token %}
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception (no such column: articles_article.author_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\daniel\site\djangosite\articles\views.py in article_list
    return render(request, 'articles/article_list.html', {'articles': articles}) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
articles    
Error in formatting: OperationalError: no such column: articles_article.author_id
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/articles/'>
```

Comment: Você executou as *migrations* da sua aplicação antes de rodá-la?

Comment: sim
mas fala aque não tem nada para migrar

Comment: Olá amigo, acabei de solucionar o problema, no final era conflito com artigos antigos que não haviam autor, eles foram criados em testes antes de adicionar a função, apos deletar o arquivo de banco de dados, e refazer com o migrate, voltou a funcionar. Obrigado pela ajuda. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao que parece a sua exceção foi gerada porque o seu template não está encontrando o campo renderizado pela `view`. O Django não está encontrando no banco de dados a coluna `articles_article.author_id`.

Se puder, posta a sua view `article_list` e o template para verificação.

De qualquer forma, verifique se seu template tem o expressão `articles_article.author_id`. Se tiver retira o article deixando-o assim: `articles.author_id` e veja se funciona.

Att.

Comment: Olá amigo, eu não havia me atentado para isso, depois de ler seu comentario fui fazer uma busca, e descobri que o comflito era no banco de dados, onde haviam artigos de testes antigos, antes de colocar para adicionar o autor, apos deletar meu banco de dados antigo e criar outro com migrate voltou a funcionar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)